# Centos apache config

Tags: linux, vmware, iptables, httpd.conf, centos6.5

Hi I am trying to reach my centos Virtual machine which i created inside in a VMware vcenter using http://server-IP/ but couldn't have access using http. but i can access it using ssh. in the **httpd.conf** file i tried to change

**"Listen 80" to Listen 8080**
in the iptables also i have added the rule

```
**"-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT"**
```

But i still couldn't access it in my internet browser.
need help to fix this . Thanks

Comment: can you indent the code

Answer (score 0):

Which version on CentOS exactly ?

What you could try, temporarily, is to disable iptables/firewalld (depending on your version), and see if you can access your website. If you can't, then at least you know it's not a firewall problem.

Comment: Actually it worked when I stopped the iptables and can access my vm using http://server-ip:8060/. But i need the iptables rule to work as i will be using this centos 6.5 vm for nagios server.

Answer (score 0):

What is the port your apache listening, 80 or 8080?
If you want to redirect 8080 to 80, use the following rule:

iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080

that will redirect all the traffic from 8080 to 80.

Can you run **netstat -nltp** and put here the output?

Comment: apache is listening on 8080

Comment: tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25                0.0.0.0:*                   LIST                                                                                                                                                             EN      1050/master
tcp        0      0 :::8080                     :::*                        LIST                                                                                                                                                             EN      7528/httpd

Comment: Did you try to run: iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080 ?

Comment: yes I tried it but i got this error : "iptables: Applying firewall rules: iptables-restore v1.4.7: Line 15 seems to have a -t table option."

Comment: What do you think is the problem? @Stas

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 8080 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --sport 8080 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

Also make sure that the order of the rules is the right one. Sometimes there is a more restrictive rule after your rules.

Comment: this was the default rule : *filter
**:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
-A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
-A FORWARD -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited**